# How to get TabIndex property of currently active control?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, controls, tabindex

How do I find the `TabIndex` property of the control who has the active focus at runtime.
I am using UlitmateEditor(Text Editor) i.e User Control , so i want focus inside the body of that Editor.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should be able to just do:

```
alert(document.activeElement.tabIndex);
```

The should get you the active control and its tab index.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.tabindex.aspx

Comment: Whoops, I didn't read that correctly, you were looking for the control that has active focus.

Comment: This link may help you...along with the link above: http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-6884.html

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK asp.net is a technology for serving HTML pages =)
If you want to know tabindex of current element in HTML, then you should use
`document.activeElement.tabIndex`. this seems to be javascript question, though.

Comment: i tried this couldn't get it working. I have text editor user control so trying to get focus inside of it.